# Case Statement '%x%' issue

Tags: sql, case

Can someone help me with why this part of my query is not working?? I'm at a loss.

```
SUM(
    CASE 
        WHEN o.Climate = 'Climate'
        AND(
            o.[UnitType] NOT LIKE '%Apartment%'
            OR o.[UnitType] NOT LIKE '%Billboard%'
            OR o.[UnitType] NOT LIKE '%Cell%'
            OR o.[UnitType] NOT LIKE '%Commercial%'
            OR o.[UnitType] NOT LIKE '%Office%'
            OR o.[UnitType] NOT LIKE '%Retail%'
            OR o.[UnitType] NOT LIKE '%Mystery%'
            OR o.[UnitType] NOT LIKE '%Mail%'
            OR o.[UnitType] NOT LIKE '%Shred%'
            OR o.[UnitType] NOT LIKE '%Truck%'
            OR o.[UnitType] NOT LIKE '%RV%'
            OR o.[UnitType] NOT LIKE '%Parking%'
            )    
        THEN o.[TotalUnits]
        ELSE NULL
    END
        ) AS [Climate Controlled Units - Total]
```

I am still getting sums for "OFFICE/WAREHOUSE" in my totals?

Comment: Case _expression_, not statement. (Since it returns a value.)

Comment: If you think about your logic properly, you will realize that satisfying any one of the `OR` statements will return true.  So `Office` will satisfy the first  statement so it will not even execute the rest of the `OR`s.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `AND` instead of `OR`:

```
SUM(
    CASE 
        WHEN o.Climate = 'Climate'
        AND(
            o.[UnitType] NOT LIKE '%Apartment%'
            AND o.[UnitType] NOT LIKE '%Billboard%'
            AND o.[UnitType] NOT LIKE '%Cell%'
            AND o.[UnitType] NOT LIKE '%Commercial%'
            AND o.[UnitType] NOT LIKE '%Office%'
            AND o.[UnitType] NOT LIKE '%Retail%'
            AND o.[UnitType] NOT LIKE '%Mystery%'
            AND o.[UnitType] NOT LIKE '%Mail%'
            AND o.[UnitType] NOT LIKE '%Shred%'
            AND o.[UnitType] NOT LIKE '%Truck%'
            AND o.[UnitType] NOT LIKE '%RV%'
            AND o.[UnitType] NOT LIKE '%Parking%'
            )    
        THEN o.[TotalUnits]
        ELSE NULL
    END
        ) AS [Climate Controlled Units - Total]
```

Explanation:

`'OFFICE/WAREHOUSE' IS NOT LIKE '%Apartment%'` => TRUE so cond1 OR cond2 OR cond3 ... OR condN is True.